# Create OSGI Service which requires user parameter

Tags: java, service, osgi, apache-felix

I'm just starting to learn osgi. Need create application, which provide Search Service. Search Service depends on the platform (SearchServiceLinux, SearchServiceAndroid, SearchServiceXXX ...). Also search service depends on a parameter that the user enters. Parameter is mandatory.

My Search Service Consumer (Then user set the parameter i create new instance of SearchService):

```
@Component(immediate = true, publicFactory = false)
@Provides(specifications = {TestConsumer.class})
@Instantiate
public class TestConsumer {
    @Requires(filter = "(factory.name=package.ISearchService)")
    private Factory mFactory;
    private ComponentInstance mSearchComponentInstance;
...
    public void userSetParameter(String pParameter) {
        Properties lProperties = new Properties();
        lProperties.put("instance.name", mFactory.getName() + "-" + pParameter);
        lProperties.put("Parameter", pParameter);

        if (mSearchComponentInstance != null) {
            mSearchComponentInstance.dispose();
        }

        try {
            mSearchComponentInstance = mFactory.createComponentInstance(lProperties);
        } catch (UnacceptableConfiguration e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MissingHandlerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My Search Service:

```
@Component
@Provides(specifications = {ISearchService.class}, strategy = "SINGLETON")
public class TestServise implements ISearchService{
    @ServiceProperty(name = "Parameter", mandatory = true)
    private int mParameter;
...
```

Questions:
1) Is this true structure of the program? @ServiceProperty or @Property more preferable in this case? What is the best practice for OSGI Service which requires parameters from user input? Is it possible to reform the structure of the consumer to use:

```
@Requires (filter = "need filter for SearchService with Parameter=XXX or create this service")
ISearchService mSearchService;
```

2) Can be applied in this situation iPOJO Event Admin Handlers?

Consumer:

```
@Publishes(name = "p1", topics = "userChangeParameter")
private Publisher mPublisher;

public void userChangeParameter(String pParameter) {
    Properties lProperties = new Properties();
    lProperties.put("Parameter", pParameter);
    mPublisher.send(lProperties);
}
```

Search Service:

```
@Subscriber(name = "s0", topics = "foo")
public void subscriber(Event pEvent) {
    System.out.println("Subscriber : " + pEvent.getProperty("Parameter"));
}
```

3) What is the best structure to create a service that depends on the parameters entered by the user? Maybe the problem is solved easily by using Apache Felix Subprojects?

I use apache felix 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a service like this:

```
@Component(
        metatype = false)
@SlingServlet(
        paths = { "/bin/test/service" }, methods = { "POST" }, extensions = { "json" },
        selectors = { "selector1", "selector2"}, generateComponent = false)
public class TestConsumer extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
   //inject all the services here like SearchServiceLinux, etc. 
   @Reference 
   private SearchServiceLinux searchServiceLinux;
}
```

You can use this service like

```
http://localhost/bin/test/service.seletor1.html
```

Now based on selector you can decide which class will handle the request means you can decide that seletor1 will be handled by class X and selector2 will be handled by class Y

If parameters are mandatory then I would recommend you to accept only POST on this service and make sure you provide search parameters in POST say parameter name is `searchParam`, so based on selector you can decide the handler and you can pass `searchParam` to this handler to generate search results.

Hope this helps.